# HTML5 Canvas DrawImage method

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am using 'drawImage()' method of HTML5 in my JS file to draw an image in screen. But the image is not getting displayed in screen. I am using the following codes. I dont understand what wrong am I doing here.No errors found on console.

It would be so great if anybody can help me..

```
Code to draw Image(failed)
=========================
var image = new Image();    
image.onload = function() {
console.log("Image has loaded");
 // body.appendChild(image);
ctx.drawImage(image,leftStart,areaBox.top+height/4,20, height/2);
};

image.src = "/MyProject/resources/base/images/close.png";
```

Also I could draw rectangle box using strokeRect()method.

```
Code to draw rectangle (success)
================================


ctx.strokeRect(leftStart, areaBox.top + height/4, 20, height/2);
```

leftStart is X co-ordinate. (areaBox.top + height/4) is the Y co-ordinate. Last two params are the width and height.

leftStart: 1500

areaBox.top: 39

height: 45

Answer (score 0):

Your code for loading the image an drawImage is fine as long as your x,y,width,height parameters of drawImage are valid.  So double-check your parameters to drawImage for validity.

In particular I see you use `areaBox.top` but you don't use `areaBox.height`--just `height`.